# Start countdown after php page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a browser training button. When the user clicks the " Brench Press" button his "Strength" increases by a php file that i've set in the form action and it checks some values and inserts values to the database that shows up.

What my problem and what i would like some help with is to implement my clock function that sets a countdown from 30 seconds to 0. This should be a countdown that the users has to watch and wait for untill he can "train" again. So somehow i need to write this clock function to output after the php file has been loaded and not onclick on the button as of now. And also for the clock not to refresh it's countdown on page refresh but keep going.

What i tried to do is to create a session with the function call inside and send it to the site so it loads after the php file has loaded but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$_SESSION['CountDownBenchPress'] = "<script> countdown(); </script>";
```

```js
var time = 30;
function countdown()
{
  if(time==0)
  {
    window.location.reload();
  }
  else
  {
    tmptime = time;
    dayTime = 24*60*60;
    hourTime = 60*60;
    minutesTime = 60;

    days = Math.floor(tmptime/dayTime);
    tmptime = tmptime - days*dayTime;

    hours = Math.floor(tmptime/hourTime);
    tmptime = tmptime - hours*hourTime;

    minutes = Math.floor(tmptime/minutesTime);
    tmptime = tmptime - minutes*minutesTime;

    seconds = tmptime;
    tidtext="";
    if(days>0)
      tidtext = days+ hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds";
    else if(hours>0)
      tidtext = hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds";
    else
      tidtext =  minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds";

    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = tidtext;
    time--;
    setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="" action="" method="">
            <td data-th="Workout"><input type="submit" onclick="countdown()" name="" value="Bench Press"></td>

            <div id="timer"></div>

          </form>
```

Comment: Why don't you try to do it with jquery?
Easiest way to do it is : 
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // do whatever you like
});

Comment: Or just stick the call to the method right before `</body>`

Comment: maybe because you use input type=submit. Try input type=button. That's because submit technically redirects you to antoher page

Comment: I dont want it to display on every page load or anything like that. I want it to display after my php file has ran and inserted everything to the database.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var time = 30;
function countdown()
{
  if(time==0)
  {
    window.location.reload();
  }
  else
  {
    tmptime = time;
    dayTime = 24*60*60;
    hourTime = 60*60;
    minutesTime = 60;

    days = Math.floor(tmptime/dayTime);
    tmptime = tmptime - days*dayTime;

    hours = Math.floor(tmptime/hourTime);
    tmptime = tmptime - hours*hourTime;

    minutes = Math.floor(tmptime/minutesTime);
    tmptime = tmptime - minutes*minutesTime;

    seconds = tmptime;
    tidtext="";
    if(days>0)
      tidtext = days+ hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds";
    else if(hours>0)
      tidtext = hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds";
    else
      tidtext =  minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds";

    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = tidtext;
    time--;
    setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="" action="" method="">
            <td data-th="Workout"><input type="button" onclick="countdown()" name="" value="Bench Press"></td>

            <div id="timer"></div>

          </form>
```

you must put input type="button" instead of submit. That's because the submit redirects you to the action page that you wrote in the form (in your case, nothing)

**EDIT** I didn't notice the auto-click part. To solve it, you must modify the body tag as it follows

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('clickme').click()">
```

and the button like this

```
<input type="button" id="clickme" onclick="countdown()" name="" value="Bench Press">
```

Comment: Yeah but the issue is that, as i wrote the Strength button reads from a php file that inputs data to the database and then redirect back to the page. If i change it to type = button it wont redirect to my form action.

Comment: if you want to redirect it just write <script>window.location.replace("myfile.php");</script>

Comment: anyway, just try this code i wrote for you. When it goes from 30 to 0, at 0 it starts the countdown again, maybe is this what you're looking for?